# MapServer return available mapfiles

Tags: mapserver

With an enormous amount of mapfiles in one directory, is it possible to return a list of available mapfiles?

I run  MapServer in a docker container:

```
docker run -d -p 8181:80 -v $MAPDATA:/map bjoernschilberg/docker-alpine-mapserver
```

A single mapfile is available with:

```
localhost:8181/cgi-bin/mapserv/?map=/map/1990.map&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities&
```

Comment: ls /map/*.map ?

Comment: Mapfiles are not meant to be visible for web users. If you want to publish a list of available mapfiles make a separate html page for that purpose.

Comment: You don't get the map file with your example request. You get a WMS response based on the content of one (or more) map file(s)~note a map file can include one or more map files